# Open a eclipse Editor programmatically

Tags: eclipse, editor

I am trying to add eclipse editor in 'open with' menu for files with a particular extension.
I do that with launcher in org.eclipse.ui.editors extension point.In the launcher I use "open editor" method which requires to pass editor Id. Is there any way such that we can open a editor programmatically without passing the editor ID? Can we open editor programmatically by passing the instance of the class which implements the editor?..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on the [IDE class's function openEditor()](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/ide/IDE.html):

```
IFile fileToOpen = ...
IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                                .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
IDE.openEditor( page, fileToOpen );
```

Note that a few checks might be important here (if the file exists or not, can be opened, you can access the active page - it is not `null`, etc.)